# Tomcat7 PPA for Ubuntu LTS 10.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, java, ubuntu-10.04

Does anyone know of a ppa / repo that will install tomcat7.  I know I can install from source but I'd rather if possible use a PPA/Repo.

I found a nice one for sun*cough*oracle-java but there does not seem to be anything for tomcat7 as of yet.

I've installed tomcat6 without issue and like the layout.  We are in the process of certifying our application for tomcat7 and I would like to have a solid production ready setup.

Here is the the cheat for installing sun*cough*oracle-java on a clean Ubuntu LTS server:

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sun-java-community-team/sun-java6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk

ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/apt$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: Look like they added tomcat7 to Ubuntu 11.10  Does anyone know if they will back port the server to LTS?
Nice and simple:   
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk tomcat7

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install tomcat7 from Debian's testing repository without any (or, worst case, with minor) dependency issues. Might not be a good idea to keep that repository updated, but then you can always sync the contents of http://cdn.debian.net/debian/pool/main/t/tomcat7/ locally on your machine and alert yourself in case of a new version.